# Upload two images in codeigniter, but one of them is replace another image

Tags: codeigniter

image name in database only 'nama_ktp' and it must be two name, 1 is 'foto_ktp' and name 2 is 'foto_laporan'

Controller : Pelaporan.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_pelaporan','pelaporan');
}
public function index()
{
    $data['konten']='pelaporan';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
public function tambah_laporan()
{
    # code...
    $foto_ktp = $_FILES['foto_ktp']['name'];
    $foto_laporan = $_FILES['foto_laporan']['name'];
    if($foto_ktp !== ""){
        if(file_exists($upload_dir.$file_name)){
            show_error('file already exist');
        }
        else{
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/';
        $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $config['file_name']='foto_ktp';
        $config['overwrite'] = false;
        $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
        $this->upload->do_upload('foto_ktp');
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
        }   
    }
    if($foto_laporan !== ""){
        if(file_exists($upload_dir.$file_name1)){
            show_error('file already exist');
        }
        else{
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $config['file_name']='foto_laporan';
        $config['overwrite'] = false;
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('foto_laporan');
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name1 = $a.$upload_data['file_name'];
        }   
    }   

    $this->pelaporan->simpan_laporan($file_name,$file_name1,$foto_ktp,$foto_laporan);

    redirect('pelaporan','refresh');    
}
```

Model : M_pelaporan

```
class M_pelaporan extends CI_Model {
public function simpan_laporan($nama_file,$nama_file1)
{
    if($nama_file==""){
    $object = array(
        'id_kasir'=>$this->session->userdata('id_kasir'),
        'laporan'=>$this->input->post('laporan'),
        'lok_laporan'=>$this->input->post('lok_laporan')
        );
    }else{
    $object = array(
        'id_kasir'=>$this->session->userdata('id_kasir'),
        'laporan'=>$this->input->post('laporan'),
        'foto_ktp'=>$nama_file,
        'foto_laporan'=>$nama_file1,
        'lok_laporan'=>$this->input->post('lok_laporan')
        );
    }

    return $this->db->insert('laporan',$object);
}
```

View : pelaporan.php

```
<form action="<?=base_url('index.php/Pelaporan/tambah_laporan')?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Laporan</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="laporan" class="form-control"><br>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Foto KTP</td>
                                <td><input type="file" name="foto_ktp" class="file" multiple="true"><br>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Foto laporan</td>
                                    <td><input type="file" name="foto_laporan" class="file" multiple="true"><br>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Lokasi laporan</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="lok_laporan" class="form-control"><br>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="submit" name="simpan" value="simpan" class="btn btn-success"></td>
                                        </tr>
                        </table>
    </form>
```

This code is upload 2 image but the first image named 'foto_ktp' is always replace with the previous uploaded photo it should sequence example foto_ktp1,foto_ktp2.The other input image named 'foto_pelaporan' can upload image but the name when uploaded is 'foto_ktp' that should named 'foto_laporan'and also with sequence number

Comment: what u do for the sequencing of file , i mean u have to do query with your db for the file name get file name then increment with +1 every time u upload the file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with this

```
public function tambah_laporan()
{

    // Upload First Image -  
    $image_data1 =  $this->uploadImage('foto_ktp');
    $image1_name = isset($image_data1['file_name']) ? $image_data1['file_name'] : '';


    // Upload Second Image -  Same Conditions Applied As in the First Image
    $image_data2 =  $this->uploadImage('foto_laporan');
    $image2_name= isset($image_data2['file_name']) ? $image_data2['file_name'] : '';


    $this->pelaporan->simpan_laporan($image1_name,$image2_name);
    redirect('pelaporan','refresh');    
}
```

Add this method inside your Controller - This method is used to upload image it can also return image validation errors if you want to ..?

```
public function uploadImage($image_name) 
{
    $upload_dir = './assets/img/'; // directory path where your files/images are uploaded.

    if($image_name !== ""){
        if(file_exists($upload_dir.$image_name))
        {
            $data['error'] = 'Image Already Exists';
        }
        else
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $upload_dir;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg';
            $config['max_size'] = '10000';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';
            $config['file_name']= $image_name;
            $config['overwrite'] = false;
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload($image_name)) {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $data['file_name'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
            }else{
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            }            
        }   

        return $data;
    }    
}
```

Model - Replace this in your model.

```
class M_pelaporan extends CI_Model {
    public function simpan_laporan($image_file1,$image_file2)
    {
        // You Don't Need Image Validation Here You Can do this in the Controller

        $object = array(
            'id_kasir'=>$this->session->userdata('id_kasir'),
            'laporan'=>$this->input->post('laporan'),
            'foto_ktp'=>$image_file1,
            'foto_laporan'=>$image_file2,
            'lok_laporan'=>$this->input->post('lok_laporan')
        );


        return $this->db->insert('laporan',$object);
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined $upload_dir

Answer (score 0):

edit this code.

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
$file_name1 = $a.$upload_data['file_name'];
```

to

```
$upload_data2 = $this->upload->data();
$file_name1 = $upload_data2['file_name'];
```